# Why can I access an object during it's post_save Signal, but not when I trigger code within that signal that calls it on another process

Tags: python, django, django-signals

All, I've got a issue with django signals.

I have a model
In an effort to speed up responsiveness of page loads, I'm offloading some intensive processing that must be done, via a call to a second localhost webserver we're running, both using the same database.  I'm seeing behavior where the calling process can retrieve the object, but the called process can't. Both port 80 and port [port] are pointing to django processes running off the same database.

In models.py

```
class A(models.Model):
    stuff...

def trigger_on_post_save( sender, instance, create, raw, **keywords):
    #This line works
    A.objects.get( pk=instance.pk )
    #then we call this
    urlopen( r'http://127.0.0.1:[port]' + 
        reverse(some_view_url, args(instance_pk) ).read()

post_save.connect( trigger_on_post_save, A )
```

In views.py

```
def some_view_function( request, a_pk ):
    #This line raises an object_not_found exception
    A.objects.get( pk=a_pk )
```

Furthermore, after the urlopen call raises an exception, the object does not exist in the database.  It was my understanding that post_save was called after the object had been saved, and written to the database.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: reverse(some_view_url, args(instance.pk) ).read() ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe post_save fires after the save occurs, but before the transaction is commited to the database. By default, Django only commits changes to the database after the request has been completed.

Two possible solutions to your problem:

1. [Manage your transactions manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transaction-management-in-views), and fire a custom signal after you commit.
2. Have your second process wait a little while for the request to go through.

To be honest though, your whole setup seems a little bit nasty. You should probably look into [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) for asynchronous task queuing.

Comment: +1 for the nod towards Celery. This is an ideal use-case for an async queue.

Comment: tbh, I'd love to get onto a Celery/RabbitMQ setup, but the previous developer already implemented his own TaskQueue system, so I was just trying to piggyback it.  Thanks for the clarification about transactions, that's exactly what I was looking for. **EDIT**: I'll keep pushing our glacial software validation team to approve something like that.

Comment: Just want to add that using celery doesn't change the issue - I've had a celery task getting old data because the transaction of the save() requested hadn't been committed yet. You either need to add a delay in your Task.run() or - better - instantiate the task "post_commit" rather than "post_save". Django doesn't provide this signal (yet) but have a look at https://github.com/davehughes/django-transaction-signals

Comment: django's default behaviur is to commit on each save, not after request has been completed. Moreover, post_save signal is sent _after_ the commit

Comment: +1 for his setup seeming nasty and celery being a better option

Comment: BTW, if you use Celery you need to call your task with a countdown because  your object won't be available yet if you don't. Example, `tasks.mytask.apply_async(kwargs={'app_model': app_model, 'pk': instance.pk, 'field': 'photo'}, countdown=1)`. Or you could use, https://github.com/chrisdoble/django-celery-transactions.

Comment: On 1.6, committed the transaction manually first before sending off to celery. Worked great so far. Example:


`from django.db import transaction
transaction.commit()
tasks.mytask.delay(...)`

Comment: Can't believe the comment by @IvanVirabyan isn't getting more upvotes, the first sentence of this answer is [patently false](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.7/django/db/models/base.py#L733).

Comment: @gdakram Forcing a commit is a simple solution but can prematurely commit a transaction if the code you are operating in is actually wrapped in a larger transaction (e.g. saving multiple objects).  Use with care.

Comment: @IvanVirabyan - `post_save` is not always called after the commit.  If you're using `@atomic` on a view the `post_save` is called _before_ the commit.

Comment: @TimTisdall yes, I said it wrong, I meant to say `post_save` is sent just after the database query is made.

Comment: I changed my complete solution using the accepted answer to find out the comment by @IvanVirabyan is the way how django handles signals and transaction.

Answer (score 17):

We ran into a similar issue and we ended up using [on_commit callback](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit) (**NOTE**: This is only possible with Django >= 1.9). So, you could possible do something like:

```
from django.db import transaction

class A(models.Model):
    stuff...

def trigger_on_post_save( sender, instance, create, raw, **keywords):
    def on_commit():
        urlopen(r'http://127.0.0.1:[port]' + 
                 reverse(some_view_url, args(instance_pk) ).read()
    transaction.on_commit(on_commit)

post_save.connect( trigger_on_post_save, A )
```

The idea here is that you wil be calling your endpoint *after* the transaction has been committed, so the instance involved in the transaction will be already saved ;).

Comment: +1: This is the neat 'batteries included' solution for Django 1.9. Note that you can even use this from the 'pre_save' signal, since it will only fire when the transaction commits, so e.g. you can alter some model attributes as required before it ever hits the database..

Comment: If you need to support Django 1.6 - 1.8 then look at https://django-transaction-hooks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ which is the source of the feature that was added in 1.9

Comment: Be careful, this approach doesn't work with ModelSerializer.create from rest framework.

Comment: @MarkMishyn did not know about that since I don't believe we were using DRF at the time. Would love to hear why it does not work with DRF.

Comment: @YoanisGil because rest framework's ModelSerializer creates instances with M2M in 2 steps, so when `Model.objects.create` is called, M2M fields are empty even with `transaction.on_commit`. You can check here https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L940

Answer (score 7):

It's nice place to use decorators. There is slightly extended version of  yoanis-gil's answer:

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def on_transaction_commit(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        transaction.on_commit(lambda: func(*args, **kwargs))
    return inner


@receiver(post_save, sender=A)
@on_transaction_commit
def trigger_on_post_save(sender, **kwargs):
    # Do things here
```

Comment: This solution seems to cause an infinite loop. If I do an instance.save() in the trigger_on_post_save function, the .save() re-triggers the @on_transaction_commit, causing a recursive loop

Comment: @Dev you don't have to call save() in signals, cause it obviously leads to recusive calls.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue when creating new model from django admin. Overriding `ModelAdmin.save_model` method to manage transaction manually worked.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    from django.db import transaction
    with transaction.commit_on_success():
       super(ModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    # write your code here
```

Comment: `commit_on_success` was removed in Django > 1.8 see this for alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861207/is-transaction-atomic-same-as-transaction-commit-on-success